# Is there a way to specify a subgroup of enumerations based on their index position in the base type?

Tags: delphi, enums, range

I have an enumeration that is was previously being used to populate a combobox by looping through it. The combobox needs to get populated with different values now depending on user input, so creating a simple subrange would work fine for one instance, but would not work at all for other instances. Is there a way to essentially "pluck" the values from a base enumeration and create a sub-enumeration of specified values in a specified order?

```
type
  TExampleEnum= (en_Planes= 1, en_Trains, en_Automobiles, en_Boats);
  ExampleGoodRange= en_Trains..en_Automobiles;
  ExampleEnumSetNeeded= en_Boats, en_Automobiles; //in this order


const
  TExampleEnumStrings: array [1 .. ord(high(TExampleEnum))
    ] of string = ('Planes', 'Trains', 'Automobiles',
      'Boats');
```

Comment: So `en_Boats` has value `4` and `1` at the same time?

Comment: By the way, `TExampleEnumStrings: array [1 .. ord(high(TExampleEnum))] of string = (...)` should probably be `ExampleEnumStrings: array [TExampleEnum] of string = (...)`.

Comment: en_Boats doesn't need to have a value of 1, it just needs to be first in the subindex so I can populate a combobox with it.

You're right about the TExampleEnumStrings, please ignore my typo haha\

Comment: @JohnWeiland best to edit your code to make it as good as it can be 

Comment: It's not clear what you would like to do with this "sub-enumeration", but is it not something that maybe you can do with a Set? Definining a specific type like TExamplesEnums = Set of TExampleNum you can then probably do most of the things you'd like... I think.